# using results from a sql query in a python program in another sql query

Tags: python, sql

sorry for my previous question which was very ambiguous, but i think if i get the answer to this question I can work it out.
In the program below i have selected the barcodes of products where the amount is less than the quantity. I want to say, that if the barcodes(in the fridge table) match barcodes in another table(products), set the stock field equal to 0. The problem Im getting is that the program is trying to match all the barcodes that it found in the query against single barcodes in the products table(thats what I think). does anyone know what to do. thanks a million. lincoln.

```
import MySQLdb

def order():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='$$', db='fillmyfridge')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select barcode from fridge where amount < quantity')
    db.commit()
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute('update products set stock = 0 where barcode = %s', row)
```

Comment: you could have corrected/edited your earlier question in place.

Comment: Your record of questions makes it clear that you are trying to learn to program. If that is true, SO is not the right place for you! Try to get the basics down first with tutorials and books that are better suited for that purpose.

Comment: For python I recommend: www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkCSpy.pdf For databases and SQL there is: http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Practical-Developers-Kaufmann-Management/dp/0122205316/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1230764439&sr=8-1 (http://tinyurl.com/86f56o)

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE products SET stock = 0 WHERE barcode IN ( 
    SELECT fridge.barcode FROM fridge WHERE fridge.amount < fridge.quantity );
```

I know this doesn't answer the question exactly but two SQL statements are not required.

To do it in python:

```
import MySQLdb

def order():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='$$', db='fillmyfridge')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select barcode from fridge where amount < quantity')
    db.commit()
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows
        cursor.execute('update products set stock = 0 where barcode = %s', row[0])
```

Comment: This example worked.. just needed a colon after `for row in rows`. Maybe because the above message was from 2008 (old Python version?).

Answer (score 4):

This is more of SQL query than Python, but still I will try to answer that:
(I haven't worked with MySQL but PostgreSQL, so there might slight variation in interpretation of things here).

when you did

```
cursor.execute('select barcode from fridge where amount < quantity')
db.commit()
row = cursor.fetchall()
```

the variable 'row' now is a resultset (to understand: a list of rows from the database)
something like [(barcode1), (barcode2), (barcode3)..]

when you do the update statement

```
cursor.execute('update products set stock = 0 where barcode = %s', row)
```

this turns into something like:

```
update products set stock = 0 where barcode = [(barcode1), (barcode2), (barcode3)..]
```

which is not a correct SQL statement.

you should do something like this:

```
cursor.execute('update products set stock = 0 where barcode in (%s)', ','.join([each[0] for each in row]))
```

or better, the optimized thing:

```
import MySQLdb

def order():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='$$', db='fillmyfridge')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('update products set stock = 0 where barcode in (select barcode from fridge where amount < quantity)')
    db.commit()
```

Well, to add more you have a db.commit() after a select query and not after an update query, thats a basic fault. Select is idempotent, doesn't need commit, whereas Update does. I will strongly recommend you to go through some SQL before continuing.

Comment: Just read your last question and its answers, comments again. I am not sure whether the two things: "what you intend to do" and "what you think will lead to that end" are in coherence. I will suggest reading the comments on the last question again and reconsidering what exactly is going around.